# Is there any geometric meaning to the collection of vectors that solves the following matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, euclidean-geometry

For the following matrix equation: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&2\\2&1&3\\3&1&4\\4&1&5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm wondering if the collection of all possible $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ that solves the above equation has any geometric meaning $R^3$. Would they form a line? A plane? Or nothing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution set to the system is the following
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}:\, t\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$
Indeed, it is the line that passes through $(1,0,0)$, with the same direction as $(-1,-1,1)$.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ (in response to your request) the system can be written as $A\mathbf{x}=b$, where
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1&1&2 \\
2&1&3 \\
3&1&4 \\
4&1&5
\end{pmatrix} \qquad \mathbf{x}=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix} \qquad b=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2\\ 3 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}$$
The augmented matrix of the system is
$$(A|\, b)=\begin{pmatrix} 
1&1&2&1 \\
2&1&3&2 \\
3&1&4&3 \\
4&1&5&4
\end{pmatrix}$$
and its reduced row echelon form is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1&0&1&1 \\
0&1&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
That is: $$\left\{\begin{align} x+z=1 \\ y+z=0 \end{align}\right.$$
Making $z=t$, we have $x=1-t$ and $y=-t$. Hence any vector solution is in the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1-t \\ -t\\ t\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: In other cases, it could be a whole plane or a single point in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it was determined that this was a line? By other cases, did you mean for other $A$ and $b$ combinations or for this example with a different $b$?

Comment: Exactly, $A$ and $b$ determine the system of equations, therefore, it depends on it. You can check a little more how I got those results (they are a bit modified, but it's the same)